# Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 4 arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, keras, lstm

I need some help to fit the compiled Keras model. In particular, I have problems with the dimensions of input data.

```
X_train =
    [[[1, 16], [1, 19], [1, 17]],
     [[1, 19], [1, 17], [0, 17]],
     [[1, 17], [0, 17], [1, 17]],
     [[0, 17], [1, 17], [1, 18]]]

y_train =
    0  1  0
    1  0  0
    1  0  0
    0  0  1
```

The input data have the following dimensions:

```
print(len(X_train), 'train sequences')
print(len(X_test), 'test sequences')
print('X_train shape:', np.array(X_train).shape )
print('X_test shape:', np.array(X_test).shape )
print('y_train shape:', y_train.shape)
print('y_test shape:', y_test.shape)

> 4 train sequences
> 1 test sequences
> X_train shape: (4, 3, 2)
> X_test shape: (1, 3, 2)
> y_train shape: (4, 3)
> y_test shape: (1, 3)
```

The shape of X should be interpreted as follows:

- Samples. Number of samples.
- Timesteps. One time step is one point of observation in the sample.
- Features. One feature is one observation at a time step.

(samples -> 4, timestamps -> 3, features -> 2)

This is Keras model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(
                units=32, # number of units returned by LSTM
                return_sequences=True, 
                input_shape=(timestamps,nb_features),
                dropout=0.2, 
                recurrent_dropout=0.2
              )
         )

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())

# model.add(TimeDistributedDense(1))
model.add(Dense(units=nb_classes,
               activation='softmax'))

# Define a performance metric
#sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics = ['accuracy'],
              optimizer='adadelta')
```

Model's summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 3, 32)             4480      
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_2 (TimeDist (None, 3, 1)              33        
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 3, 1)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 3)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 12        
=================================================================
Total params: 4,525
Trainable params: 4,525
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

In this plot, one can see that the input is `(None, 3, 2)`, which means that (4, 3, 2) of `X_train` should be ok, but for some reason it isn't.

[image]

When I execute this code, it throws an error:

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split=0.25, epochs=500, batch_size=2, shuffle=True, verbose=0)
```

Error:

> ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays
>   that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected.
>   Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 4
>   arrays: [array([[ 1, 16],
>          [ 1, 19],
>          [ 1, 17]]), array([[ 1, 19],
>          [ 1, 17],
>          [ 0, 17]]), array([[ 1, 17],
>          [ 0, 17],
>          [ 1, 17]]), array([[ 0, 17],
>          [ 1, 17],
>         ...

Comment: `np.array(X_train)` ??

Comment: @mad_ oh, thank you! you made my day!! can you explain why you suggested this conversion?

Comment: `model.fit` expects the data to be single array, which is list in your case (shown in `ValueError`).